# When call API from android emulator in react native then message shown network request failed but not in real device?

Tags: android, react-native

```
insertdata = () => {
const { pinValue1 } = this.state;
const { pinValue2 } = this.state;
const { pinValue3 } = this.state;
const { pinValue4 } = this.state;
const { pinValue5 } = this.state;
const { pinValue6 } = this.state;
var String_3 = pinValue1.concat(pinValue2);
var String_4 = String_3.concat(pinValue3);
var String_5 = String_4.concat(pinValue4);
var String_6 = String_5.concat(pinValue5);
var final_string = String_6.concat(pinValue6);
console.log(final_string);
const { email } = this.state;
console.log(email);

fetch("http://demo.theoneinfotech.com/dating/user/user_invite_code", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    invite_code: final_string
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
    console.log(responseJson);
    if ((responseJson.errorCode !=1)) {
     // Alert.alert("pass sent on your email");
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup");
      //this.props.navigation.navigate("Referal")
    } else {
      Alert.alert("Invalid invite code");
    }
    //this.props.navigation.navigate("Forgot");
    /*if (responseJson.data[0].nick_name!= null && responseJson.data[0].nick_name != "") {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Forgot"); 
    } else {
      Alert.alert("invalid pin number");
    }*/
    // Alert.alert(responseJson.message);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

};

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.insertdata}>
      <Text
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          color: "white",
          fontSize: 16,
          opacity: 5
        }}
      >
        VERIFY
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]
In the above code, I have mentioned Insertdata function for calling API and event for call API. In my case when I run code on emulator then showing above error but not on the real device. This type of issue I am facing first time please help me for fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the network connectivity. In the error screen it seems there is no network connection. connect wifi in the emulator.